# Python firebase_admin.credentials has no attribute Certificate

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently developing for GCP and had used this code already many many times (this is running on RPI3 python 3.7)

```
def createClient(projid, dev_name):
   base = os.getcwd()
   base = base.replace("\\",'/')
   keydir = '{}/Devices/{}/firebase.json'.format(base, projid.lower())
   print(keydir)
   cred = credentials.Certificate(keydir)

   firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
       'databaseURL': 'https://{}.firebaseio.com/'.format(projid.lower())
   }, name= dev_name)
```

But now the code fails with message:

> module 'firebase_admin.credentials' has no attribute 'Certificate'>

Please note this code it's working correctly in other RPI why is this not working?!

the error occurs in this line of code:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate(keydir)
```

anyone with a clue would be very very appreciated.

Kind Regards!

Edit: I've tried with:

```
cred = credentials.RefreshToken(keydir)
```

still the same result now with the error:

> module 'firebase_admin.credentials' has no attribute 'RefreshToken'>

note I'm using a service account json file as a key.

Edit2: I missed to add this info in the original post:

firebase-admin==2.17.0

this is all running in a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (RPI)

Comment: 1) Why are you formatting `keydir` that way? 2) Is `firebase.json` a service account JSON key file? 3) Most likely you want this instead: `cred = credentials.RefreshToken('path/to/firebase.json')` 4) There is an older service account file format called P12 and that format contains a certificate. The new format (JSON) has a private key instead.

Comment: Thanks! well 1) That's the actual path of the .json file this part is correct for my purposes; 2) it is, a service account key file that's why I use Certificate; 3) I will try this now but maybe this should not work because I use a service account file 4) yes that's exactly my case P12 in a JSON file.

Comment: Note that P12 is deprecated. Download the JSON key file for your service account and save yourself future headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I just got confused I'm using JSON key files not P12 I got the two options in the menu, still why this time I got the mentioned error? just tried with a JSON from the other 'working' RPI and I got the same error

Comment: Your question does not include enough details. Which library are your using and its version? Make sure first that you are using a current version of the SDK: `pip install -U firebase-admin`. BYW: What is RPI? Follow the details in this document on setting up the firebase SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: Ah, sorry I got all that info and didn't add it to the original post, I just edited with the info, BTW RPI is Raspberry Pi.